# Reading a pointer from another process memory

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi, readprocessmemory

I'm trying to read a pointer from another process. I can read the content of the pointer, and I actually receive an address, but what I want to do is to go one step beyond that and take the value inside the received address. I think i'm doing it wrong, or else I guess it's not possible the way I'm doing it?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    DWORD pid;
    int **buffer = NULL;
    cout << "Current PID: " << GetCurrentProcessId();
    cout << "\nTarget PID: ";
    cin >> pid;

    HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

    if (handle == NULL) {
        cout << "\nCant open process. Error Code: " << GetLastError();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    else {
        ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPCVOID)0x5BF9A4, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL); // &*buffer maybe?
        if (ReadProcessMemory == 0) { 
            cout << "\nRPM failed, ERROR_CODE: " << GetLastError();
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    cout << "\nBuffer: " << buffer << endl;
    //cout << "Buffer 1st hop: " << *buffer << endl; // Wont execute. Crashed maybe?
    //cout << "Buffer 2nd hop: " << **buffer << endl;
    CloseHandle(handle);
    if (CloseHandle != 0){
        cout << "Handle to process destroyed successfully.\n";
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might help to explain what is going wrong.  Is it outputting "RPM failed", crashing, locking up, or what?

Comment: My bad! All the above works fine actually and i also can read a pointer and get the address it is pointing to but what i want to see is not the address but what's inside the address. Lets say buffer stores address 10 which it read from another pointer in another process. I can output 10 no problem but what i want to see is the value inside address 10 lets say an int 5. How do i do that?

Comment: I suspect it crashes when i try to deref buffer because in this current process, buffer is initialized to point to NULL and im trying to deref a NULL so thats not gonna work.

Comment: instead of `*buffer` you need use  `ReadProcessMemory(handle, bufer, ...);`

Comment: I haven't used *buffer in code its been commented out. But i think by now i have used every combination of passing and outputting and i just tried again right now. No luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. Why did you decide to not ask a question?

Comment: Yea but you know, not every community is going to be welcoming to a new person. I usually look for the questions and take notes in my notebook. I have seen a few incredible responses that i learnt from big times though. 
I also dont want to ask questions as soon as i hit a simple block. Want to try over and over until it works. But this time it aint happening that way lol. 
I also wasn't expecting such quick responses. thanks

Comment: It seems, that comment didn't drive the point home. Let's try this again: There is no question in your 'question'.

Comment: the question is how do i read whats inside the memory address that is being stored in the buffer. Buffer is getting its content via ReadProcessMemory and the functions is reading memory address 0x5BF9A4 for pointers. It finds the pointer at the address, it takes its content(Which is a memory address) and puts it in buffer. Now that i have a mem address in my buffer I want to go to that address and see whats inside but i cant do it because if i deref my pointer (buffer) and because it was initialized with NULL, Its just gonna crash

Comment: Do not explain in a comment, what the question should be. Time to take the [tour]. Make sure to read [ask].

Comment: The value you get from address `0x5bf9a4` is a pointer in the other process. To read what it points to you need to use `ReadProcessMemory` like you did to read the value of the pointer in the first place.

Comment: oooh so u mean just call ReadProcessMemory again but with the new address that is in buffer now?

Comment: Also why is my question edited?

Comment: Jonathan, this is the most helpful 2 sentences I have ever read in my entire life. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure if I misunderstood, you may have the process like below:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int data = 10;
    int* p = &data;
    int** pp = &p;
    printf("pid = %d\n", GetCurrentProcessId());
    printf("p = %x\n",p);
    printf("pp = %x\n", pp);
    printf("address of pp = %x\n", &pp);
    return 0;
}
```

You have the address of `pp`, and want to get the value of `data`?

The address space for each process is private unless it shared. You just read the value of the local variable `pp` through the address, you also need to read the address `pp` again to get the value of `p`, and finally read the address of `p` to get the `data`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    DWORD pid;
    int** buffer = NULL;
    cout << "Current PID: " << GetCurrentProcessId();
    cout << "\nTarget PID: ";
    cin >> pid;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, false, pid);
    if (hProcess == NULL)
    {
        int error = GetLastError();
        cout << "OpenProcess error: " << error << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    int** pp = NULL;
    BOOL ret = 0;
    LPCVOID address = (LPCVOID)0xd3fe20;
    ret = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, address, &pp, sizeof(int**), 0);
    printf("pp = %x\n", pp);

    int* p = NULL;
    ret = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, pp, &p, sizeof(int*), 0);
    printf("p = %x\n", p);

    int data = 0;
    ret = ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)p, &data, sizeof(int), 0);
    printf("data = %d\n", data);

    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your time!
The problem was that i was trying to sort of make 2 hops in one instruction. But someone commented that you just call ReadProcessMemory twice only the second time with the address that was just obtained. This was the fix for it. I should have just called it twice from the get go idk why it didn't even cross my mind.
Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @ヅヅヅ Glad to help, If you only need to adjust twice to read a value like `data = 10`, then I think your `0x5BF9A4` address is an `int**` type. And the `&buffer` you pass is of type `int***`, Or `0x5BF9A4` is indeed type of `int***`, then the last thing you read is the address of `data`(`p`). Finally, you could feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it, if the answer does help.

Answer (score 1):

You have to reserve the space to put the read content:

```
char buffer[1024];
ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPCVOID)0x5BF9A4, buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL);
```

And you should get the read count in the last parameter:

```
int r = 0;
char buffer[1024];
ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPCVOID)0x5BF9A4, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &r);
```

That way you know how much data you read.

And you have to get the result from the call:

```
int r = 0;
char buffer[1024];
int ok = ReadProcessMemory(handle, (LPCVOID)0x5BF9A4, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &r);
if (! ok)
   // do something
```

After that you may read the content `buffer[0]` is the first char.

Comment: i went ahead and added `SIZE_T readCount = 0;` then in call i passed `&readCount`. I get a 4 out of it so 4 bytes of data was read which is a memory address (because we are reading a pointer which contains a mem add). I didn't have a use case for it so i set it to NULL before. But i dont see why we need a char array as our buffer. The address we tried to read was being stored in buffer no problem. The problem was i couldnt go past that address if i deref'd that because that address was read from a different process with its own set of pointers. Not sure if im clear enough